# data not show on ms access

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

i'm writing a code on c# (winform). the program is about cachier and the database is 
ms access.
when i am entering the data to the database it seems like the data was enterd but when i'm opening the ms access the table is empty. althogh, if i right click on the 'preview data set' in the visual studio, i can see the data.
here is my code so far regard to the database:

```
    private void buttonCloseCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < baught_items.Count; i++)
        {
            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\אורון\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CachierPro\CachierPro\CachierProDB.accdb";
            string temp_item = baught_items[i].ToString();
            int temp_item_quantity = baught_items_quantity[i];
            double temp_item_price = baught_items_price[i];
            double temp_total_item_price = total_items_price[i];
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Receipts (ItemName, Quantity, PricePerOne, Total) VALUES (@temp_item, @temp_item_quantity, @temp_item_price, @temp_total_item_price)", connect);
            if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add ("@temp_item", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = temp_item;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@temp_item_quantity", OleDbType.Integer, 20).Value = temp_item_quantity;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@temp_item_price", OleDbType.Double, 20).Value = temp_item_price;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@cart_sum", OleDbType.Double,20).Value = temp_total_item_price;

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Added To DataBase");
                    textBoxCurrentCartSumTXT.Clear();
                    textBoxPricePerOneTXT.Clear();
                    textBoxQuantityTXT.Clear();
                    textBoxSumForCurrentItemTXT.Clear();
                    connect.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception expe)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
                    connect.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: o.k u must understand that i'm new in ms access. in answer to your question, all i do is to open ms access and refresh the table. is this o.k? if not, where am i supose to look? thanks...

Answer (score 1):

To get any rows back from your database storage through a OleDbDataAdapter you need to set its SelectCommand with a command that contains a SELECT statement

```
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Receipts", connect);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Actually you are using the same command used to INSERT data as it was the SelectCommand. Obviously it doesn't return records. You should have a duplicate record in your table.

I would change something to your code. If you have more than one record to add to your table (you have a loop there) then there is no sense in extracting data from your db at every loop. I would call the Fill of the table outside the loop. Also a bit performance gain could be obtained defining the OleDbCommand and its parameters just one time before entering the loop. Inside the loop just update the values of the parameters and call ExecuteNonQuery

```
    private void buttonCloseCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\אורון\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CachierPro\CachierPro\CachierProDB.accdb";
        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO Receipts 
        (ItemName, Quantity, PricePerOne, Total) 
         VALUES (@temp_item, @temp_item_quantity, 
         @temp_item_price, @temp_total_item_price)", connect);

         cmd.Parameters.Add ("@temp_item", OleDbType.Char, 20);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@temp_item_quantity", OleDbType.Integer, 20);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@temp_item_price", OleDbType.Double, 20);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@cart_sum", OleDbType.Double,20);

        for (int i = 0; i < baught_items.Count; i++)
        {
            string temp_item = baught_items[i].ToString();
            int temp_item_quantity = baught_items_quantity[i];
            double temp_item_price = baught_items_price[i];
            double temp_total_item_price = total_items_price[i];
            if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@temp_item"].Value = temp_item;
                cmd.Parameters["@temp_item_quantity"].Value = temp_item_quantity;
                cmd.Parameters["@temp_item_price"].Value = temp_item_price;
                cmd.Parameters["@cart_sum"].Value = temp_total_item_price;
                try
                {
                    int addedCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if(addedCount == 0)
                    {
                       ... problems here, record not added for some reasons
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception expe)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
                    connect.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
        }

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Receipts", connect);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        textBoxCurrentCartSumTXT.Clear();
        textBoxPricePerOneTXT.Clear();
        textBoxQuantityTXT.Clear();
        textBoxSumForCurrentItemTXT.Clear();
        connect.Close();
   }
```

Comment: its throw me a "system data" exception. lt me rephrase my qustion, my friend. i can see the data threw the "data preview" in the visual studio (right click on the "dataset" explorer). the problem is that the data not transfer to the ms access when i open the program. thanks.

Comment: Could you change the catch block to show the expe.Message instead of the source?

Comment: o.k, the massege is: the property Fill: Select Command Connection is not initializes.

Comment: I see, probably you copied the first lines. Well, in the full example above the SelectCommand is outside the loop and fully initialized with a Select statement. I fix the first lines now

Comment: i changed the code according to you. it works without any exceptions but the problem stay the same. again, when i open the program "microsoft access 2010" and open the relevent table, the table is empty. it seems like the data was not insert the table at all. please help!

Comment: If the ExecuteNonQuery returns a value different than zero then it has inserted the record somewhere. Open your database in the same path used for the ConnectionString above. Move to that path using Windows Explorer and do not trust the internal tools of Visual Studio. They could be using a different connection string.

Comment: u mean to copy this: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\אורון\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CachierPro\CachierPro\CachierProDB.accdb" to "my computer"? it dosent show anything. man, i'm confused...

Comment: wait a seconed, it worked! i did it! you are a genius!!!! thanks man, now i can see all the data in my access. but why i need to open the database using the connection string and not threw mt desktop icon?

Comment: Well, something should be wrong somewhere. For sure the code use the path expressed in the connection string. So if you want to check the results you should be sure that everything you use points to that database and not somewhere else

Comment: You should look at your tools and check the path that they use to show your db